# Magento - Recently Viewed Getting Cached

Tags: magento

I have moved the recently viewed section of my magento store to the display above the footer.  You can see from the screenshot:
https://skitch.com/a1anm/ft33i/mens-watches-uk

The problem is it only displays/updates if I clear the cache.  How can I prevent this from getting cached and displaying all the time with up to date content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up disabling the footer cache using these instructions:
http://www.mage-contacts.com/magento-disable-block-cache/